# UPDATE multiple rows with the same id

Tags: mysql, group-by, row

I'm working on a MaNGOS DB. Currently I've got my own id's but I want to use the official once. The problem is that I've already got some values inside my DB which I want to update.

The table I want to update looks like this.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `character` LIMIT 10;
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| id | char_name_de                    | char_name_en | id_new       | id_old|
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
|  1 |                                 | NULL         |            2 |  NULL |
|  2 | Abgesandter des Schattenhammers | NULL         |        18201 |  NULL |
|  3 | Abgesplittertes Skelett         | NULL         |        10478 |  NULL |
|  4 | Adept aus Scholomance           | NULL         |        10469 |  NULL |
|  5 | Aduscha                         | NULL         |        18204 |  NULL |
|  6 | Aggressiver Bluthund            | NULL         |         8922 |  NULL |
|  7 | Akolyt aus Scholomance          | NULL         |        10471 |  NULL |
|  8 | Akolyt der Schmetterschilde     | NULL         |         9045 |  NULL |
|  9 | Althena                         | NULL         |        18208 |  NULL |
| 10 | Amadelis                        | NULL         |        18209 |  NULL |
+----+---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I'm trying to do: 
Replace "id" by "new_id"

Issues:
"id_new" isn't unique cause of some multi-language strings. ***I want to match them into one row, saving "id" into "id_old", replace "id" by "id_new" and delete "id_new".***

this looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM `character`
    -> WHERE id_new IN(
    -> SELECT id_new
    -> FROM `character`
    -> GROUP BY `character`.id_new
    -> HAVING COUNT(`character`.id_new) > 1
    -> )
    -> ORDER BY id_new ASC;
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| id  | char_name_de             | char_name_en | id_new       | id_old|
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| 258 | Natter                   | NULL         |         2914 |  NULL |
| 342 | Snake                    | NULL         |         2914 |  NULL |
| 290 | Rat                      | NULL         |         4075 |  NULL |
| 292 | Ratte                    | NULL         |         4075 |  NULL |
| 276 | Orakel der Hakkari       | NULL         |        11346 |  NULL |
| 152 | Hakkari Oracle           | NULL         |        11346 |  NULL |
| 148 | Gurubashi Warrior        | NULL         |        11355 |  NULL |
| 201 | Krieger der Gurubashi    | NULL         |        11355 |  NULL |
| 344 | Sohn von Hakkar          | NULL         |        11357 |  NULL |
| 347 | Son of Hakkar            | NULL         |        11357 |  NULL |
|  47 | Bloodseeker Bat          | NULL         |        11368 |  NULL |
|  51 | Blutsucherfledermaus     | NULL         |        11368 |  NULL |
| 560 | Molten Giant             | NULL         |        11658 |  NULL |
| 123 | Geschmolzener Riese      | NULL         |        11658 |  NULL |
| 545 | Flamewaker               | NULL         |        11661 |  NULL |
|  93 | Feuerschuppe             | NULL         |        11661 |  NULL |
| 546 | Flamewaker Priest        | NULL         |        11662 |  NULL |
|  94 | Feuerschuppenpriester    | NULL         |        11662 |  NULL |
| 553 | Lava Annihilator         | NULL         |        11665 |  NULL |
| 214 | Lavavernichter           | NULL         |        11665 |  NULL |
| 540 | Firelord                 | NULL         |        11668 |  NULL |
|  92 | Feuerlord                | NULL         |        11668 |  NULL |
| 543 | Flame Imp                | NULL         |        11669 |  NULL |
| 104 | Flammenwichtel           | NULL         |        11669 |  NULL |
| 536 | Core Hound               | NULL         |        11671 |  NULL |
| 194 | Kernhund                 | NULL         |        11671 |  NULL |
| 534 | Ancient Core Hound       | NULL         |        11673 |  NULL |
| 384 | Uralter Kernhund         | NULL         |        11673 |  NULL |
| 549 | Golemagg the Incinerator | NULL         |        11988 |  NULL |
| 129 | Golemagg der Verbrenner  | NULL         |        11988 |  NULL |
| 558 | Majordomo Executus       | NULL         |        12018 |  NULL |
| 240 | Majordomus Exekutus      | NULL         |        12018 |  NULL |
| 554 | Lava Elemental           | NULL         |        12076 |  NULL |
| 212 | Lavaelementar            | NULL         |        12076 |  NULL |
| 564 | Sulfuron Harbinger       | NULL         |        12098 |  NULL |
| 359 | Sulfuronherold           | NULL         |        12098 |  NULL |
| 541 | Firesworn                | NULL         |        12099 |  NULL |
|  90 | Feueranbeter             | NULL         |        12099 |  NULL |
| 557 | Lava Surger              | NULL         |        12101 |  NULL |
| 215 | Lavawoger                | NULL         |        12101 |  NULL |
| 556 | Lava Spawn               | NULL         |        12265 |  NULL |
| 211 | Lavabrut                 | NULL         |        12265 |  NULL |
| 297 | Razzashi Raptor          | NULL         |        14821 |  NULL |
| 301 | Razzashiraptor           | NULL         |        14821 |  NULL |
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
44 rows in set (0.23 sec)
```

How to solve:
This Query would do what I want, but there is one problem, MySQL can't UPDATE an Table which you use for an select subquery.

```
UPDATE `character`
SET `character`.id_old =    (
    SELECT `character`.id
    FROM `character`
    GROUP BY `character`.id_new
    HAVING COUNT(`character`.id_new) > 1
    )
WHERE `character`.id_new IN (
    SELECT `character`.id_new
    FROM `character` 
    GROUP BY `character`.id_new
    HAVING COUNT(`character`.id_new) > 1
    );
```

So I have to create an temp_table with all values I need:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp_character` (
    `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_new` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

And fill it with Values:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_character (id, id_new)
SELECT id, id_new
FROM `character`
WHERE id_new IN(
    SELECT id_new
    FROM `character` 
    GROUP BY `character`.id_new
    HAVING COUNT(`character`.id_new) > 1
    )
ORDER BY id_new ASC;
```

***Now I've got this Query:***

```
UPDATE `character`
SET `character`.id_old =    (
    SELECT tmp_character.id
    FROM tmp_character
    GROUP BY tmp_character.id_new
    HAVING COUNT(tmp_character.id_new) > 1
    )
WHERE `character`.id_new IN (
    SELECT tmp_character.id_new
    FROM tmp_character 
    GROUP BY tmp_character.id_new
    HAVING COUNT(tmp_character.id_new) > 1
    );
```

Problem now: ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
That's true, I've got 22 different id's to update and I've got 22 GROUPS, don't know why it won't work.

After this Query my Table should look like this:

```
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| id  | char_name_de             | char_name_en | id_new       | id_old|
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| 258 | Natter                   | NULL         |         2914 |  258  |
| 342 | Snake                    | NULL         |         2914 |  342  |
| 290 | Rat                      | NULL         |         4075 |  290  |
| 292 | Ratte                    | NULL         |         4075 |  292  |
| 276 | Orakel der Hakkari       | NULL         |        11346 |  276  |
| 152 | Hakkari Oracle           | NULL         |        11346 |  152  |
| 148 | Gurubashi Warrior        | NULL         |        11355 |  148  |
| 201 | Krieger der Gurubashi    | NULL         |        11355 |  201  |
| 344 | Sohn von Hakkar          | NULL         |        11357 |  344  |
| 347 | Son of Hakkar            | NULL         |        11357 |  347  |
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
.
.
.
```

Now "id_new" should be unique like this:

```
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| id  | char_name_de             | char_name_en | id_new       | id_old|
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| 258 | Natter                   | NULL         |         2914 |  258  |
| 290 | Rat                      | NULL         |         4075 |  290  |
| 276 | Orakel der Hakkari       | NULL         |        11346 |  276  |
| 148 | Gurubashi Warrior        | NULL         |        11355 |  148  |
| 344 | Sohn von Hakkar          | NULL         |        11357 |  344  |
+-----+--------------------------+--------------+--------------+-------+
.
.
.
```

Now I want to delete column "id_new" to get my final table.

```
+-------+--------------------------+--------------+-------+
| id    | char_name_de             | char_name_en | id_old|
+-------+--------------------------+--------------+-------+
| 2914  | Natter                   | NULL         |  258  |
| 4075  | Rat                      | NULL         |  290  |
| 11346 | Orakel der Hakkari       | NULL         |  276  |
| 11355 | Gurubashi Warrior        | NULL         |  148  |
| 11357 | Sohn von Hakkar          | NULL         |  344  |
+-------+--------------------------+--------------+-------+
.
.
.
```

Could anyone help me modify my query to make it run? I need to fix Query after highlighted "Now I've got this Query:", rest would be easy and I get it my own, I just posted it cause of background what I want to have at the end.

Comment: Your expected output is not clear to me.  Can you update your question with a clean table which is related to your first one?

Comment: By the way, you did a great job formatting your first question.

Comment: i've seen it too and update it now. I modified row names a little bit for posting here because of better understanding.

Comment: Now it should be updated, i hope ;)

Comment: I made a dirty sollution using php.

Comment: If you think your answer works correctly, then why not post your own solution?

Comment: Because i havn't seen the Answer-Button and Comment alows not enough characters xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my script to move values from id to id_old where i've got more than one line:

```
<?php
  function executeQuery($dbConnection, $Query) {
    $result =  $dbConnection -> query($Query);
    return $result;
  }


  function openDB() {
  $dbConnection=  new mysqli($mServer, $mUser, $mPwd, $mDatabase);
    return $dbConnection;
  }

  // open Database
  $DBconnection=openDB();

  // 1st query
  $query="SELECT *
          FROM `character` c
          WHERE c.id_new IN(
            SELECT c.id_new
            FROM `character` c
            GROUP BY id_new
            HAVING COUNT(id_new) > 1
          )
          ORDER BY id_new ASC;";

  // sent query to database
  $result=executeQuery($DBconnection, $query);
  $numRows=$result->num_rows;

  // do as long as you've got rows
  for(;$numRows>0;$numRows--) {

    // go to next row
    $currentRow=$result->fetch_object();

      $id_new=$currentRow->id;
      $query="UPDATE `character` c
              SET c.class=" .$id_new ."
              WHERE c.id IN(" .$id_new .");";
      echo $query ."\n";
      $result2=executeQuery($DBconnection, $query);
   }
  }

?>
```

And this one is an second modified version which would delete the second row if one row is doubled. If one row would be trippled or more, it won't work!

```
<?php
  function executeQuery($dbConnection, $Query) {
    $result =  $dbConnection -> query($Query);
    return $result;
  }


  function openDB() {
  $dbConnection=  new mysqli($mServer, $mUser, $mPwd, $mDatabase);
    return $dbConnection;
  }

  // open Database
  $DBconnection=openDB();

  // 1st query
  $query="SELECT *
          FROM `character`
          WHERE id_new IN(
            SELECT id_new
            FROM `character`
            GROUP BY `character`.id_new
            HAVING COUNT(`character`.id_new) > 1
          )
          ORDER BY id_new ASC;";

  // send query to database
  $result=executeQuery($DBconnection, $query);
  $numRows=$result->num_rows;

  // as long as you've got rows
  for(;$numRows>0;$numRows--) {

    // go to next row
    $currentRow=$result->fetch_object();
    for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {
      if($i==0) {
        // skip 1st line from each row which is doubled
        $currentRow=$result->fetch_object();
      }

      // delete 2nd line from each row which is doubled
      $id_new=$currentRow->id;
      $query="delete from `character`where id=" .$id_new .";";
      $result2=executeQuery($DBconnection, $query);
   }
  }


?>
```

But as i said, it's a dirty script!

How it works?
I use some Values of one Query in a Second Query. I promisse it would work without php but sometimes a quick and dirty soluction is better than a good one which takes several days!

//close